# Which ranges of IPv6 and IPv4 do requests to the local network and the host?

Tags: ipv4, firewall, ipv6, layer3, ip-range

I'm looking for the range of IP address that is bound to the local network or the host itself.

So far for IPv4 I found:

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
- 127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255
- 169.254.1.0 - 169.254.254.255 (not sure?)

For IPv6 I found:

- ::1/128
- fd00::/8
- fe80::/10 (not sure?)

Can you help me to complete this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) is the authority for this. There are many pages maintained by it, including some that directly address what you want:

- *[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)*
- *[IPv4 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml)*
- *[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)*
- *[IPv6 Multicast Address Space Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml)*

You can see things like: Address Block, Name, RFC, Allocation Date, Termination Date, Source, Destination, Forwardable, Globally Reachable, Reserved-by-Protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very helpfull and it is maintained. I will certainly continue to use this links.